# what happens after opening files in java

Tags: java, file

suppose that using a JFilechooser , we choosed a text file which contained 1 line , say... "hello world"

```
File file = new File("someFile.txt")
```

when we print the file contents we get `"hello world"`
but what happens if we changed the text file contents and added some new lines  , and printed again , does java stores the file in memory ? or it will reads it again , and consequently prints the new lines we added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you do. The rules are simple: when you read it again by using a `FileInputStream` or a `FileReader`, you will always get the latest content. The OS might optimize this in memory, if the file is not edited. If you simply keep the file contents into a self constructed buffer (e.g.: a `String` or a `byte[]`), and the file changes, of course the buffer will remained unchanged.

Comment: Yes, I added that to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `File`, nothing actually happens. The location of the file is stored, nothing else. It's like setting your GPS to go somewhere versus driving there.

From the Javadoc:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

When you read from the file, you'll get the contents of the file.